# Pentaho bi-server unable to detect JAVA_HOME

Tags: installation, pentaho

I just installed the latest bi-server from sourceforge (5.0.1A) in OSX mavericks.
and I get the following error :

```
sudo ./start-pentaho.sh 
/usr/local/pentaho/biserver-ce
/usr/local/pentaho/biserver-ce
WARNING: Using java from path
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. The reason being the server was installed in a location that required root permissions.